# Columns with missing values not dropping

Tags: python, pandas, drop

The code below doesn't drop **all** (it does drop some) columns where null values exist, how come? Does it make distinctions between None, np.nan, etc?

```
columns_to_drop = [x for x in X.columns if X[x].isnull().sum()>0]
print(columns_to_drop)

dropped_X = X.drop(columns_to_drop,axis = 1).copy()
```

Neither does the simpler:

```
X.dropna(axis=1, how='any')
```

Imputing values isn't an option.

Finally, I had to drop rows where missing values existed, after having dropped all columns where missing values existed (clearly I hadn't though)

```
columns_to_drop = [col for col in X2.columns if X[col].isnull().any()]
print(columns_to_drop)

dropped_X = X.drop(columns_to_drop,axis = 1).copy()
dropped_X2 = X2.drop(columns_to_drop,axis=1).copy()

dropped_X2.dropna(axis = 0, how = 'any',inplace = True)
```

Having ran that last line I was able to proceed. Why did I have to, though?

Comment: You need either X = x.dropa ... or X.dropna(...inplace=True)

Comment: Please show your dataset